# How to use/pass a script tag variable within a style tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, report

I'm creating a reporting tool for my Automation E2E Suite and I have a majority of it working so far nice and smoothly.  I'm a little stuck at the moment on how to pass and/or use a variable that I've created in a script tag to alter the value of a style tag.

So basically what this segment of my report will do is create some metrics for test results (total tests, total passed, skipped, and failed) and then creates a circle which should adjust accordingly to the metric of the results (e.g. 10 total tests with 5 passing results in the passed circle to be a semi circle to represent 50%).

Here's how it looks in code at the moment:

```
    '<script type="text/javascript">' +
        'document.getElementById("titleHeader").textContent = "' + title + '";' +
        'var passed = document.querySelectorAll("li.passed").length;' +
        'var failed = document.querySelectorAll("li.failed").length;' +
        'var skipped = document.querySelectorAll("li.pending").length;' +
        'var total = passed + failed + skipped;' +
        'document.querySelector("div.item.passed h2").textContent = passed;' +
        'document.querySelector("div.item.failed h2").textContent = failed;' +
        'document.querySelector("div.item.skipped h2").textContent = skipped;' +
        'document.querySelector("h2.totalTestAmount").textContent = total;' +
        'var passedCircle = (440-((passed/total)*440));' +
        'var failedCircle = (440-((failed/total)*440));' +
        'var skippedCircle = (440-((skipped/total)*440));' +
    '</script>' +
```

The three variables created at the end of the script will result in the value represented by the dash-offset property below which I would like to pass to in a style tag.

```
    '<style>' +
       '@keyframes passed {' +
         'to {' +
       'stroke-dashoffset: passedCircle;' +
         '}' +
       '}' +
    '</style>';
```

I've tried doing a global type in the script tag by `window.passedCircle` however that didn't work either.

I'm curious if there's a way to do this type of modification after the page has been entirely written and loaded.

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to do but can you check if `stylesheet.insertRule(rule, index)` works for you? It allows you to insert rules to your style via Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I ended up finding a method that worked for me using something similar to your advice.  I'm not familiar with css/javascript so after some research I was able to utilize the stylesheet properties and found the appropriate rules needed for the overwrite and passing of variables.